# CppUnit test hangs with Qt 5.9

Tags: c++, qt5, cppunit

While porting our source code from Qt 5.6 to Qt 5.9.1 an issue has come up when testing with CppUnit 1.13.2: `DllPluginTester.exe` hangs when having successfully performed all unit tests on finishing. When debugging into the process the stack shows that

> CppUnit::DynamicLibraryManager::doReleaseLibrary()

gets stuck calling `::FreeLibrary`, and further up the stack hangs in `QThread::wait()`, i.e. `WaitForSingleObject` waits forever.

Has anybody an idea what can cause such a behavior?

Comment: If you have a full stack trace you can open a bug report with all the neccessary details at the TDF bugzilla. I have never heard of such a problem but suppose that not too many people are still using the qttestrunner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of that issue: c.f. [QTBUG-34460](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34460).
I don't know why the issue did not discover before moving from Qt version 5.6 to 5.9.1, since the bug was reported already for version 5.1.1. So investigation took some time.

For the affected tests - which all of them were involved in some kind of multithreading, e.g. by calling `QtConcurrent::run()` somewhere - I inserted the following lines at the end of each affected test as my solution:

```
void UnitTestClass::testWithMultithreadingInside
{
  ...
  constexpr auto MAX_WAIT_MS = 5000;
  auto pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
  if (pool)
  {
    pool->clear();
    pool->waitForDone(MAX_WAIT_MS);
  }
}
```